# React Native Push Notifications with delete()

Tags: react-native, react-native-firebase, react-native-push-notification

I am learning react-native-push-notifications with react-native-firebase. I want to receive a push notification upon deleting a user. The deletion is working fine. However, taking several tutorials online and doing different things, I am unable to receive notifications. Can somebody guide me how to change this in order to get a push notification as well, upon clicking the "Delete User"? Thanks in advance.

```
export default class UpdateInfo extends Component {  
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { 
      displayName: '',
      email: '', 
      isLoading: false
    }
  }
    deleteUser = () => {
      firebase.auth().currentUser.delete().then(() => {
        console.log("The user was deleted successfully")
      }).catch(function (error) {
        console.error({error})
      })
    }

  render() {
    if(this.state.isLoading){
      return(
        <View>
          <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#9E9E9E"/>
        </View>
      )
    }    
    
    return (
      <View>
        <TouchableOpacity 
          onPress={() => this.deleteUser()}
          >
          <Text>DELETE USER</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>

    );
  }
}
```

Comment: User your are deleting is from Admin Application or User Perform Delete Operation.?

Comment: All you need to do is generate an fcmtoken and save that in db(real-time/firestore/anyelse). Then when you perform a delete operation call fcmPushnotification api. You'll receive push notification. 

But more important Push Notification Will Not Appear if App is in opened/Active state

Comment: So If you wat notification receive when App State is active I prefer localNotification from
react-native-push-notification